# how do we plot bar chart in lightningchartjs

Tags: lightningchart

Is there a way to draw a simple bar chart on x axis and y axis like  . I need a bar chart on x : 0 and height till y: 10 , then x:1 and height till y:5 like that ?

I need to share the x axis with different axis.

Comment: **Try writing something yourself** and then if it doesn't work, show us specifically what you did so we can help you along. You start it, and then we help. We don't write it for you. **Show us the actual code that you've tried**, and then describe what happened and what's not right, and then we can help you from there. Chances are you'll get pretty close to the answer if you just try it yourself first.

Comment: hi , this is specific to lightningchart library , I dont see anything in their documentation , So I wanna know if this thing is available.

Comment: Would suggest looking at examples https://lightningchart.com/lightningchart-js-interactive-examples/

Comment: I see barchart with { category: 'A', value: 20 }, I need with { x: 0, y: 20 } , is that possible ?